# Multiple nested forms of same type - submit from first one only posts form_build_id of parent form

Tags: forms

10 forms of the same type, each with one submit button (which have distinct `#name` attributes), nested within a parent form of a different type. They are nested simply by calling `drupal_get_form()` from within another form callback (why am I doing it this way? Well, I have some display suite fields that call `drupal_get_form()`, and I am rendering some entities within the parent form, so rendering those entities calls `drupal_get_form()` within the parent form function).

All work perfectly, except for the first one of the 10. When its submit button is pressed, the correct `_triggering_element_name` is posted, but the `form_build_id` posted is the build id of the parent form, not the child form. For all subsequent 9 forms, the correct `_triggering_element_name` and `form_build_id` are posted, and they work perfectly.

The HTML seems to be the same for each of the 10 subforms, i.e. the first one has the hidden `form_build_id` input, which has its own distinct value from that of the parent form. This value is just not posted.

Any thoughts? I'm a bit stumped! Even just an idea of where to look to see what's wrong...

Comment: Could you describe a bit more about what you mean by "nested forms"? HTML doesn't allow nested forms so it'd be good to know how you're simulating that to best advise. If you can post a version of the code that demonstrates it, even better

Comment: Good point Clive! I've updated the question.